# Autentication Azure ad Client Secret is necessary?

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I have the following doubt, I have a project that is based on microsoft authentication, a frontend with angular using msal and the backend with passport-azure-ad.
My question is the following, is it necessary to use the client secret?

Comment: Sorry i am noob on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are using authorization code flow or hybrid flow in OpenID Connect, the **client exchanges an authorization code for an access token**. During this step, the **client has to authenticate itself to the server**. One way to authenticate the client is by using a client secret.

**Client secret is required for web apps** which can store the client_secret securely on the server side.All confidential clients have a choice of using client secrets or certificate credentials and  passport azure ad library is designed for auth flows in server side web apps.

> **Note**:ClientID and Client Secrets are  passed to AAD by MSAL, and if you are using a confidential client (like: WebApp, WebAPI or
> Daemon/Service) that runs on Azure PaaS Service, or any other secured
> servers,  only the clientID gets exposed by MSAL but not the client
> secret, as the client secret is passed only in the backend (server
> side) to AAD and never directly exposed and requires proper
> authentication.

[msal client apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications)

If your app is native(spa), client secret is not needed

Public clients, which include native applications and single page apps, must not use secrets or certificates when redeeming an authorization code as  client_secret can't be reliably stored on devices or web pages and the secret can be vulnerable to attacks if it is client side exposed..

**Reference:** [v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow-Client secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#:%7E:text=the%20PKCE%20RFC.-,client_secret,in%20the%20Authorization%20header%2C%20per%20RFC%206749%20is%20also%20supported.,-Request%20an%20access)

Comment: my application is angular pwa so I don't need client secret, is this correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct ! Angular is usually used to design Single Page Applications(spa) and as i said spa need not use client secret. But also please note that " SPA can be a PWA, but a PWA doesn’t necessarily have to be a SPA"